# timestamp is not getting converted in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a field in Table A named `sentDate` of type `bigint(20)` which stores the timestamp value. now when i want to use `sentDate` field's value into Table B to perform some query operation i am not getting any results.

to debug that i tried following

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(sentDate) from Table A;
```

but i am getting all `NULL` values , it seems its not converting the time stamp value properly.

i want to use `sentDate` in a Table B ( using subquery )  but as sentDate is not being converted properly i am getting null result.

sample timestamp value is `1403944186539` ,i have tried this timestamp on 
 `http://www.epochconverter.com/` online tool and its showing results there

Comment: give some sample value which are there in sentDate with expected date

Comment: use this `1403944186539`

Comment: As it seems your `sentDate` column contains milli seconds fraction too, simply use `from_unixtime( setDate / 1000 )`, which converts it into regular `datetime` format. And if you want only date part, then use `date( from_unixtime( setDate / 1000 ) )` to fetch date only in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this , You are giving millisecond but `from_unixtime` takes second since  `1/1/1970`.

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(sentDate/1000) from Table A;
```